# Having an issue with letters bleeding into the next section?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Hey guys im learning to get my HTML and CSS better. I am having trouble with some text bleeding into other panels. I've tried looking at the developer tools and I tried using the position: relative attribute to no avail. I have tried moving the text in the h1 field of the CSS code and haven't had any luck. Im still learning so I am pretty sure it is something obvious.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RazorPagesAllegiant</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/RazorPagesAllegiant.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#1">First</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Second</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Third</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">Fourth</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Fifth</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

<div class="sections">
    <section id="1"><h1>Meet Our Client</h1></section>
    <section id="2"><h1>Second</h1></section>
    <section id="3"><h1>Our Advisors</h1></section>
    <section id="4"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
    <section id="5"><h1>Background</h1></section>
    <section id="6"><h1>First</h1></section>
    <section id="7"><h1>Problem / Proposed Solution</h1></section>
    <section id="8"><h1>Third</h1></section>
    <section id="9"><h1>Highlights</h1></section>
    <section id="10"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
    <section id="11"><h1>Scope</h1></section>
    <section id="12"><h1>Second</h1></section>
    <section id="13"><h1>Prototypes</h1></section>
    <section id="14"><h1>Fourth</h1></section>
    <section id="15"><h1>Timeline</h1></section>
    <section id="16"><h1>Fifth</h1></section>
</div>

<script class="cssdeck" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    background: #1ABC9C;
}

    nav ul {
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

        nav ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

            nav ul li a {
                padding: 10px 0;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                transition: all 0.2s ease;
            }

                nav ul li a:hover {
                    color: #34495E;
                }

a.active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ecf0f1;
}

/* Headings */

h1 {
    font-size: 5rem;
    color: #34495E;
    position: relative;
}

/* Sections */

section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

    section:nth-child(even) {
        background: #C4C4C4;
        text-align: center;
        height: 500px;
    }

    section:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #fff;
        text-align: left;
        height: 10px;
    }

.sections section:first-child {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

section.active {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend using `z-index` to ensure your `nav` bar stays in front of the scrolling text:

```
nav ul {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

It seems the bleeding as to do with your odd and even ids; if any of your odd "id" text spans more than one line, it will guarantee spill into the even items. To fix this, I would try setting your odd-section `height` to `auto` instead of specifically `10px`. This will make the section larger if the text spans more than one line and essentially push your even IDs below the text in the odd IDs, resolving the bleeding text:

```
section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    height: auto;
   
}
```